# Avoid overlapping of coordinates in plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have created a tikzpicture but many coordinates overlap.

Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{C0504D}
\definecolor{ggreen}{HTML}{008000}
\definecolor{ppurple}{HTML}{9F4C7C}
\definecolor{mustard}{HTML}{cc9900}

\newcommand{\avtwo}{\texttt{2AVG}}
\newcommand{\avplus}{\texttt{AVG + AVG/2}}
\newcommand{\av}{\texttt{AVG}}
\newcommand{\avgdivt}{\texttt{AVG/2}}
\newcommand{\avgdivf}{\texttt{AVG/4}}
\newcommand{\avgdive}{\texttt{AVG/8}}

\title{Graphs}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure*}
\centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
      \begin{axis}[
            ylabel={y axis},
             xlabel = {Thresholds},
              width  = 1.8*\textwidth,
             height = 18cm,
               scaled y ticks = false,
                y tick label style={font=\large},
                 y label style={font=\Large},
                  x tick label style={font=\large},
                 x label style={font=\Large},
               y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.001,.5)},anchor=south},
            symbolic x coords={\avtwo, \avplus, \av, \avgdivt, \avgdivf, \avgdive},
            xtick=data,
            x tick label style={},
            nodes near coords align={vertical},
            legend cell align=right,
       legend style={font=\Large,at={(0.173,1.12)},
            anchor=north,legend columns=-1}
        ]

        \addplot [only marks,mark=square*,mark size=4pt,color=red,mark options={solid},solid] coordinates{ 
            (\avtwo,98.83) (\avplus,98.48) (\av,97.84) (\avgdivt,96.25) (\avgdivf,94.04) (\avgdive,90.92) 
        };
        \addplot [only marks,mark=*, mark size=4pt,color=bblue,solid] coordinates{ 
               (\avtwo,98.71) (\avplus,98.16) (\av,97.33) (\avgdivt,96.07) (\avgdivf,94.69) (\avgdive,92.53)
        };
         \addplot [only marks,mark=asterisk, mark size=5pt,color=ggreen,solid] coordinates{ 
               (\avtwo,90.53) (\avplus,87.82) (\av,82.43) (\avgdivt,69.49) (\avgdivf,54.42) (\avgdive,40.93)
        };
         \addplot [only marks,mark=triangle*, mark size=5pt,color=ppurple,solid] coordinates{ 
               (\avtwo,92.34) (\avplus,90.2) (\av,86.01) (\avgdivt,75.71) (\avgdivf,64.1) (\avgdive,53.96)
        };
         \addplot [only marks,mark=diamond*, mark size=5pt,color=mustard,solid] coordinates{ 
               (\avtwo,90.33) (\avplus,87.58) (\av,82.31) (\avgdivt,69.84) (\avgdivf,58.12) (\avgdive,48.12)
        };



        \legend{DP,TR,SP,TR\_SP,SP\_TR}
    \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

The output produced is:

[image]

Is it possible to scale the y axis in order to avoid overlapping?

Comment: Consider to at least to upvote the provided answer since it seems to solve the problem.

Comment: In addition, your code example seems to contain many unrelated packages. It's recommended to remove unrelated code when posting your problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can install user transformations. Whether or not this is of great help in this specific situation I can't decide.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{C0504D}
\definecolor{ggreen}{HTML}{008000}
\definecolor{ppurple}{HTML}{9F4C7C}
\definecolor{mustard}{HTML}{cc9900}

\newcommand{\avtwo}{\texttt{2AVG}}
\newcommand{\avplus}{\texttt{AVG + AVG/2}}
\newcommand{\av}{\texttt{AVG}}
\newcommand{\avgdivt}{\texttt{AVG/2}}
\newcommand{\avgdivf}{\texttt{AVG/4}}
\newcommand{\avgdive}{\texttt{AVG/8}}

\title{Graphs}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure*}
\centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
      \begin{axis}[
            ylabel={y axis},
             xlabel = {Thresholds},
              width  = 1.8*\textwidth,
             height = 18cm,
               scaled y ticks = false,
                y tick label style={font=\large},
                 y label style={font=\Large},
                  x tick label style={font=\large},
                 x label style={font=\Large},
               y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.06,.5)},anchor=south},
            symbolic x coords={\avtwo, \avplus, \av, \avgdivt, \avgdivf, \avgdive},
            xtick=data,
            x tick label style={},
            nodes near coords align={vertical},
            legend cell align=right,
       legend style={font=\Large,at={(0.173,1.12)},
            anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{-ln(99-#1)}},
            y coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{99-exp(-#1)}}
        ]

        \addplot [only marks,mark=square*,mark size=4pt,color=red,mark options={solid},solid] coordinates{ 
            (\avtwo,98.83) (\avplus,98.48) (\av,97.84) (\avgdivt,96.25) (\avgdivf,94.04) (\avgdive,90.92) 
        };
        \addplot [only marks,mark=*, mark size=4pt,color=bblue,solid] coordinates{ 
               (\avtwo,98.71) (\avplus,98.16) (\av,97.33) (\avgdivt,96.07) (\avgdivf,94.69) (\avgdive,92.53)
        };
         \addplot [only marks,mark=asterisk, mark size=5pt,color=ggreen,solid] coordinates{ 
               (\avtwo,90.53) (\avplus,87.82) (\av,82.43) (\avgdivt,69.49) (\avgdivf,54.42) (\avgdive,40.93)
        };
         \addplot [only marks,mark=triangle*, mark size=5pt,color=ppurple,solid] coordinates{ 
               (\avtwo,92.34) (\avplus,90.2) (\av,86.01) (\avgdivt,75.71) (\avgdivf,64.1) (\avgdive,53.96)
        };
         \addplot [only marks,mark=diamond*, mark size=5pt,color=mustard,solid] coordinates{ 
               (\avtwo,90.33) (\avplus,87.58) (\av,82.31) (\avgdivt,69.84) (\avgdivf,58.12) (\avgdive,48.12)
        };



        \legend{DP,TR,SP,TR\_SP,SP\_TR}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that your plot is too wide (I did not fix this), your preamble loads many things that are not used here, `\tt` was already deprecated at the end of the last Millennium, and it is good practice to switch to the current version, which is currently `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please explain in more details the added lines? Also, is it possible to scale the y axis in several "places"? For example, in 2AVG there are the other three values that overlap(SP, TR_SP, SP_TR). Can I do the same as for DP, TR?

Comment: @Telperinquar All I did was to install a user transformation. These transformations are explained in great detail in section **4.21 Symbolic Coordinates and User Transformations** of the pgfplots manual v1.16. And yes, it is possible to define the transformation in such a way that it zooms in at other locations.

Answer (score 1):

- In my opinion, this is *not* a `pgfplots`-specific question (not even a LaTeX-specific question).
- This is an issue, that applies to diagrams in general.
- **Basically, you can optimize the following parameters: `height` (bigger is better), and the difference between `ymin` and `ymax` (bigger is better).**
- Of course, you can also change the size of the marks (`mark size` or `mark options`) (smaller is better).

Comment: One commonly used approach is to add some "jitter" to the x values... in this diagram, if the OP used numbers for the x-values, and kept the category labels for the axis, they could be shifted left and right a little bit to avoid the overlap.

Comment: @Thurston That's a clever approach. Thanks for the suggestion.